# response.sendRedirect should open in a new window

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, redirect

```
String contextPath="http://chf-www05/manuals";
response.sendRedirect(contextPath +"/zseries9.pdf");
```

This redirect is from a servlet and it is redirecting to a PDF residing on an external webserver. The task is the pdf should open in a new window when this servlet is being called. I tried the 'window.open' using a '' tag but it didn't work as desired.

Comment: Are you calling the servlet from a webpage jsp, html?

Comment: try [`window.open("http://chf-www05/manuals/zseries9.pdf")`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and hit it directly from javascript.

Comment: Nope!! I am calling it from a struts action servlet.

Comment: `response.sendRedirect()` doesn't open a new window.

Comment: yes! i know. Is there a way that could work? may be not with response.sendRedirect but any other method?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening like this:

```
window.open("url","_blank");
```

this will open in new tab or window.

Answer (score 0):

Open tab or new window can not be programmaticly possible because it's browser's option.
Also you can use anchor(a) tag with target blank attribute. If you redirect or forward, it does not open in new window or tab

Answer (score 0):

I just added target='_blank' in the form tag and did not change anything in the servlet. It worked!